# How to calculate diminishing returns between two %s on a variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves, percentages

Suppose I have Damage = 100, and I have Damage Up +20%(or any % up) as well as Magic Up +20%.

Both variables modify Damage equally but at what point is it better to work on Damage Up vs Magic Up and vice versa? I assume it's some sort of bell curve but I have no idea to determine the high point of this curve, where the return is most optimal (for example Damage Up +70% and Magic Up +80% would be equal and putting points into either will net the same benefit.

Comment: Well if both affect the damage equally then I really don't see a difference. Or have I understood the question wrong? Would you care to elaborate in detail?

Comment: If they affected it like so Damage * Magic Up * Damage Up would that change anything? If not how would I go about calculating if one influences the stat more or less as you suggest?